# Personalizar atributos de produtos no woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, atributos

Atualmente, até onde sei, os atributos são criados na edição do produto em "Dados do Produto", no woocommerce. 
Ao inserir o Valor do atributo:

```
30 | 60 | 90 |
```

É gerado um *drop-down* no frontend.
No entanto, *eu preciso que seja gerado um **RADIO***. Como posso personalizar esse atributo para tal fim? Devo editar o core ou há uma possibilidade pelo admin?

Comment: Como (quase) tudo no WooCommerce, tem um filtro para get_attributes: http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#1363. Tem que dar uma olhada no template do produto pra ver como ele interage com o frontend...